# Where to put logic that will never gets displayed?

Tags: angular

I've an ionic/angular app. On this app I'm implementing the localization.

The goal would be:

**To get the current culture:**

- If the user is logged in, get the language from its profile
- If the user isn't logged in, get the language from the browser

**To set the current culture:**

- If the user is logged in, store the language in its profile

I've one module for the auth stuff, I've one module for the localization stuff.

I was thinking to have some code set somewhere that would do:

- When the application starts, register to the current user changes and if the user is changed, call the localization service to switch language
- When the language change, if the user is logged-in, store the new language

I see exactly the code I need to do, but I'm not sure WHERE I should put this? directly inside the module seems dirty, if I put it in a service, I still need to call some method to activate it.

Where is the right way to put such kind of logic?

Comment: You can register a `Subject` in the initialization phase in some service which handles the `translation` on its own when some state changes, so you don't need to activate manually

Comment: have a look at [authGuards](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-auth-guards-tutorial-with-example/#.X3GH2GgzaUk). may be it will be helpfull for you.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanFalyoun you could put your service or that piece of logic in your autGuard service which definitely you would be having to take care of authentication.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanFalyoun The 2 services already provides some observable to register on. My question is more where should I put this?

Comment: @FarhatZaman I already have authGuard setup, but `guard` only execute on specific page, and everytime you go on those page, right?

Comment: You can put it on your root route so that it gets called executed every page, and set a property on a service. [link](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-resolve/) `route resolvers`. You can either set data on a service from your resolver, or return the data. They are ideal for when you store state in your URL, as they maintain the same behaviour if you navigate to the page using the url, refresh the page, or route to that route via the UI.

Comment: Yeah I see, but I don't use URL for language